# How to escape sprintf() % marks so they wont be recognized as variables?

Tags: c++, windows

So is this even possible? If i some day wanted to `sprintf(str, "%doodle %d", var);` output "%doodle 123" and not "123oodle", how can i stop the first %d from being processed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

%% escapes the %

Comment: In what way? What is the usage? Do you surround the initial % with two %%? Or do you just put one in front of it?

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade You'd do it like this: `sprintf(str, "%%doodle %d", var);`