# How to escape the symbol of percentage '%' in r?

Tags: r, escaping, special-characters

In an url, I am dealing with the special character '**%**' that I should pass as a string. The url contain some argumnents so I use `sprintf.` How to escape the symbol '**%**' in r ?

```
start <- 1
#%s is my variable
url<-(sprintf('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s?rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A502394%2Cn%3A281052%2Cn%3A12556502011%2Cn%3A3017941&page=%s&ie=UTF8', start, start))
```

> invalid format '%2Cn%3A'; use format %s for character objects

Comment: Did you meant %d instead of %s?

Comment: To escape the symbol you use double percentage signs, i.e. '%%'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206496/how-to-escape-sprintf-marks-so-they-wont-be-recognized-as-variables

Comment: i.e. `url<-(sprintf('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s?rh=n%%3A172282%%2Cn%%3A%%21493964%%2Cn%%3A502394%%2Cn%%3A281052%%2Cn%%3A12556502011%%2Cn%%3A3017941&page=%s&ie=UTF8', start, start))`

Comment: @Alex thanks, I didn't consider it because it was in C++

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the helpfile for `sprintf` states:

> A wrapper for the C function sprintf, ...

Thus, you escape it in `R` the same way you do for `C`, using double precentage signs `%%` to produce one `%`, as per

[How to escape sprintf() % marks so they wont be recognized as variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206496/how-to-escape-sprintf-marks-so-they-wont-be-recognized-as-variables)

On your code, we produce a url presumably extracting the first page in this amazon.com search:

```
url<-(sprintf('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_%s?rh=n%%3‌​A172282%%2Cn%%3A%%21‌​493964%%2Cn%%3A50239‌​4%%2Cn%%3A281052%%2C‌​n%%3A12556502011%%2C‌​n%%3A3017941&page=%s‌​&ie=UTF8', start, start))
```

produces

```
> url
[1] "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A502394%2Cn%3A281052%2Cn%3A12556502011%2Cn%3A3017941&page=1&ie=UTF8"
```